# Div scrolled to the top of the page when anchor link inside an horizontal-scroll element is clicked

Tags: html, css, overflow, horizontal-scrolling, anchor-scroll

I am playing with creating an horizontal slider with pure CSS
for some reason clicking on the anchor link to scroll the elements on the x axis also scroll the entire page on the y axis, placing the slider at the top of the page

Can this behavior be avoided
(as you can see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior it work as it should)

see GIF below and the code I wrote
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    html {
      scroll-timeline: --progress-bar
    }
    
    body {
      height: 300vh;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .progress-bar {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 10;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 0.25em;
      transform-origin: 0 50%;
      background: red;
      animation: grow-progress;
      animation-duration: auto;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-timeline: --progress-bar;
      transform: scaleX(0);
    }
    
    .gallery-wrap {
      width: 100%;
      height: 600px;
      background: pink;
      padding: 100px 20%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .gallery-frame {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .gallery {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
      scroll-timeline: --progress-bar inline;
      align-items: center;
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
      scrollbar-width: none
    }
    
    .gallery::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .index-bar {
      height: 6px;
      width: 100%;
      background: red;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      animation: grow-progress;
      animation-duration: auto;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-timeline: --progress-bar;
      transform-origin: left;
      transform: scaleX(calc(1 / 3));
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .nav {
      width: 100%;
      background: #ffffff69;
      position: absolute;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      padding: 16px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .nav a {
      width: 36px;
      display: block;
      aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
      background: black;
      border-radius: 100%;
    }
    
    .slide {
      width: 100%;
      flex-shrink: 0;
      scroll-snap-align: center;
      align-self: stretch;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .slide .nav {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .screen1 {
      background: #fff0ce;
    }
    
    .screen2 {
      background: #e4f1fd;
    }
    
    .screen3 {
      background: #ccfff5;
    }
    
    @keyframes grow-progress {
      to {
        transform: scaleX(1);
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="progress-bar"></div>
  <div class="gallery-wrap">
    <div class="gallery-frame">
      <div class="gallery">
        <div class="index-bar"></div>
        <div class="nav" style="pointer-evet:none">
          <a href="#slide1"></a>
          <a href="#slide2"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="slide1" class="slide screen1">
          <div class="nav">
            <a href="#slide3"></a>
            <a href="#slide2"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="slide2" class="slide screen2">
          <div class="nav">
            <a href="#slide1"></a>
            <a href="#slide3"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="slide3" class="slide screen3">
          <div class="nav">
            <a href="#slide2"></a>
            <a href="#slide1"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have a typo with `pointer-evet:none`

Comment: technically you wont be able to do this right without using JS, but you can go with `margin-top:-30%` in such case it will keep on top as you're target is almost on 30% of page, But it will be used as a static solution, so if you tried at another position it will affect for only -30% up,  also it will affect your other slides buttons current position, as it will consider the current target is moved alone

Comment: the margin is not a good solution, what if this slide would be in the middle of a long scrolling page

Comment: you could use css var() to set a variable for the margin, but still you need to set it through the JS, as there is no way to override browser actions without using JS as even if you stopped pointer events, you will not be able to go to the next slide, .. will get stuck at the same point again ...

Answer (score 1):

```js
 const scrollLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll-link');

    scrollLinks.forEach(link => {
      link.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default behavior of anchor links
        const targetId = link.getAttribute('data-target');
        const targetElement = document.getElementById(targetId);
        if (targetElement) {
          targetElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
    .nav a {
      width: 36px;
      display: block;
      aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
      background: black;
      border-radius: 100%;
      cursor: pointer; /* Add cursor pointer to make it clear it's clickable */
    }

 html {
      scroll-timeline: --progress-bar
    }
    
    body {
      height: 300vh;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .progress-bar {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 10;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 0.25em;
      transform-origin: 0 50%;
      background: red;
      animation: grow-progress;
      animation-duration: auto;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-timeline: --progress-bar;
      transform: scaleX(0);
    }
    
    .gallery-wrap {
      width: 100%;
      height: 600px;
      background: pink;
      padding: 100px 20%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .gallery-frame {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .gallery {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
      scroll-timeline: --progress-bar inline;
      align-items: center;
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
      scrollbar-width: none
    }
    
    .gallery::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .index-bar {
      height: 6px;
      width: 100%;
      background: red;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      animation: grow-progress;
      animation-duration: auto;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-timeline: --progress-bar;
      transform-origin: left;
      transform: scaleX(calc(1 / 3));
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .nav {
      width: 100%;
      background: #ffffff69;
      position: absolute;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      padding: 16px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .nav a {
      width: 36px;
      display: block;
      aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
      background: black;
      border-radius: 100%;
    }
    
    .slide {
      width: 100%;
      flex-shrink: 0;
      scroll-snap-align: center;
      align-self: stretch;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .slide .nav {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .screen1 {
      background: #fff0ce;
    }
    
    .screen2 {
      background: #e4f1fd;
    }
    
    .screen3 {
      background: #ccfff5;
    }
    
    @keyframes grow-progress {
      to {
        transform: scaleX(1);
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="progress-bar"></div>
  <div class="gallery-wrap">
    <div class="gallery-frame">
      <div class="gallery">
        <div class="index-bar"></div>
        <div class="nav" style="pointer-events: none">
          <a class="scroll-link" data-target="slide1"></a>
          <a class="scroll-link" data-target="slide2"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="slide1" class="slide screen1">
          <div class="nav">
            <a class="scroll-link" data-target="slide3"></a>
            <a class="scroll-link" data-target="slide2"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="slide2" class="slide screen2">
          <div class="nav">
            <a class="scroll-link" data-target="slide1"></a>
            <a class="scroll-link" data-target="slide3"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="slide3" class="slide screen3">
          <div class="nav">
            <a class="scroll-link" data-target="slide2"></a>
            <a class="scroll-link" data-target="slide1"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this modified code, I've added a `data-target` attribute to the anchor links and given them a class of `scroll-link`. The JavaScript code intercepts the click event on these links, prevents the default behavior, and scrolls to the target element with a smooth animation. This way, clicking the links won't scroll the entire page on the y-axis.

Comment: This still scrolls the page up when those links are clicked

Comment: Additional to @ChrisBarr comment, OP required CSS only code, so it doesn't make sense to use JS inside your answer,

Comment: I don't want to use JS, as I mentioned I want to use pure CSS

Comment: @ZivFeldman Scrolling to an element when an anchor is clicked is just part oh how browsers work. It's going to do this as long as you are not interfering with that default behavior, and the only way to do that is with JS